# Parsing filelists.xml from Bash or C?

Tags: xml, bash, parsing, rpm, file-listing

I'm trying to parse a `filelists.xml` (the metadata of the RPMs).

The tag looks like:

```
<package pkgid="b63972e0b2442412bd81bcb24065e264c02bc3fc" name="basesystem" arch="noarch"><version epoch="0" ver="10.0" rel="3_WR4.1.0.0" /></package>
```

I need to parse the data on this format: `package.name-version.ver`

For instance on the example above it would return: `basesystem-10.0`

I would like to use Bash or C.

Comment: with bash, i tried with sed and awk commands.
with c, i tried to read line by line and start taking the text between "name=\"" and "" ".
i think the better way to try again with bash.

Comment: In my opinion it's not enought information. A good option would be to use a `xml` parser of `perl` or `python`, but I don't know which format has `filelists.xml`. If all lines have same elements and attributes in same order perhaps `sed` or `awk` could be enought, but who knows... Given that input I would extract the data by hand with copy & paste :-)

Comment: `egrep -o '(name|ver)="[[:alnum:]\.]+"' | paste -s -d' \n'` will give you just the desired key/value pairs. From there you can manually parse them out, or you can just `eval` them with the shell if you're confident about the safety of the data.

Comment: Why `bash` or `C`? Most RPM-based distros now use `yum` and that has a ton of `python` code available to handle it.

Comment: this function will be at embedded system, so i would implement it via C or BASH.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to get data from XML in bash, think of `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//package' -v '@name' -o '-' -v 'version/@ver'-o $'\n'
```

This matches nodes named "package" anywhere in the tree, and writes the value of the "name" attribute, a dash, the value of the "ver" attribute in a sub-element named "version", and finally a line feed.

This is simpler and safer than trying to treat the XML file as text, and won't break for completely valid `fileutil.xml` files that just happen to wrap lines differently.